# How to run nested React map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON I need to fetch data & display in UI but not able to do due to nested.

JSON data:

```
data =[
  {
        "First Row": {
            "info": 274.176,
        }
    },
    {
        "Second Row": {
            "info": 139.536,
        }
    }
]
```

My Code:

```
{data
                ? data.map((val, i) =>
                    val[i].map((val2) => {
                      <>
                        <div>{val2.info}</div>
                      </>;
                    })
                  )
                : ""}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.values()` to get an array of all the values, then use `[0]` to get the first object where you can acces the `info` as desired:

```
data.map((val, i) => Object.values(val)[0].info)
```

```json
[
  274.176,
  139.536
]
```

```js
const data = [
    { "First Row": { "info": 274.176, } },
    { "Second Row": { "info": 139.536, } }
];

const r = data.map((val, i) => Object.values(val)[0].info);
console.log(r)
```

Comment: how can i get only first value ? instead of all

Comment: If you only want the first value there is no need to use map or iterate in the first place. Just use `data[0]['First Row'].info`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only the info value, you can do the following. It loops through the data array. And for each item, gets the value of the first key. (assuming each item only has one key)

```
const DataDisplay = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h3>{Object.keys(item)[0]}</h3>
            <div>{Object.values(item)[0].info}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```